# Powershell get-date format to calendar date

Tags: powershell-3.0

Is there a method,library or formatter to get the calendar serial date?

For example (for 2017) Jan 1 is 001 and Feb 2nd will be 033.

Looking to create case numbers like YY-xxxx (17-033).

Thanks

Comment: Not clear what you are asking

Comment: each day of the current year increments the number by 1 being jan 1, the last day of the year is 365 (or the max for that year). like the julian date.

Comment: The returned object is a datatime so you should be able to do get-date.DayOfYear or something to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

This might work. PowerShell 3 is not my strong suit.

```
PS > get-date

Friday, January 27, 2017 4:06:52 PM

PS > ((get-date).DayOfYear).ToString("D3")
027
```

"D3" is a [standard numeric format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) in .NET.

This expression will return the "case number" you're looking for.

```
(Get-Date).ToString("yy") + '-' + ((Get-Date).DayOfYear).ToString("D3")
17-027
```

`Get-Date | Get-Member` is an education.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Date` returns a `DateTime` object so you should be able to do `Get-Date.DayOfYear` or something to that effect and just format it to suit your needs

```
$date = Get-Date

$caseNumber = [String]::Format("{0:yy}-{1:0##}", $date, $date.DayOfYear)
```